# Weird behavior: Placeholder not appearing on the textarea

Tags: html, css

I want to make a "comments plugin", so I started with the markup and a few styles.

Everything was fine until I added the `textarea` element

The HTML code for that element is:

```
<textarea rows="7" cols="37" placeholder="Ingrese su comentario">
</textarea>
```

But something weird happened, because when I loaded the page, a default text appears in the textarea.

1. **Q1: What do you think is happening?**
2. **Q2: How fix it?**

Here's a [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fTF38/)

Thanks,
Leonardo

PS: If it works, I work with Chrome 27.0.1453.116 version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove line break in textarea from the markup. Any space, html formatting causes inclusion of space, newline etc between the textarea opening and closing tags and they are considered as the text and hence placeholder was not appearing for the textarea as it is not empty technically.

Change this:

```
 <textarea rows="7" cols="37" placeholder="Ingrese su comentario">
  </textarea>
```

to :

```
<textarea rows="7" cols="37" placeholder="Ingrese su comentario"></textarea>
```

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nqvHD/)

and just give your textarea a `padding-left` to be consistent with other input boxes

```
textarea
{
   padding-left:10px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! The problem was so stupid, but was about to make me crazy! Thanks again =)

Comment: @LeonardoManrique not really stupid infact... textarea is really weird it is easy to confuse it with input types.

Comment: Yeah textarea is one of those quirky html features. Check out this article if you would like to learn a bit more about it: http://css-tricks.com/textarea-tricks/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe its Chrome AutoFill, wanting to help u fill your form. Choosing an Id or a name for the textarea, which is unique, should help.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense, read [PSL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17247563/weird-behavior-default-text-in-textarea-element#17247577)s answer...